# Version of Node.js which not supperted by hardhat, but I have LTS version of node

Tags: node.js, solidity, remix, hardhat

I installed nvm in Ubuntu 20.04. Then using nvm I installed node and npm.
The general task is to use hardhat in my Solidity project.
I created npm project and installed hardhat:

```
npm init
npm install --save-dev hardhat
```

Then I created a simple hardhat project: `npx hardhat`.

But now, I can't use any tasks from hardhat(like `npx hardhat accounts`) due to this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPF1u.png)
I use the lts version of node 16.14.2, [here is a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3leW.png) from the command `nvm ls`.

I thought that I installed node but not node.js(actually I still don't fully understand the difference between node and node.js), so I installed node.js using `sudo apt install nodejs` but this does not help.

So, I don't know what to do, because I have LTS version of node, but seems like hardhat can see this.

Also, I wanted to use hardhat plugin in remix IDE but [there is no such plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pai8.png)

UPD: I think, I found the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmDp6.png). But I even don't have 17.7.2 version. [This is the all versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p4eb.png) that I have. So now, I think, I have to somehow say to hardhat my node version

Comment: I'd suggest not to install nodejs from the package manager of your distribution, because they are oftentimes quite outdated. Better use something like `nvm` like you originally did. Did you check which version of node you are running? (What is the output of `node --version`) Did you check which versions of node are supported by hardhat?

Comment: @derpirscher I tryed three versions: 18.0.0, 16.14.2 and 16.0.0. With each of them I have the same error. The Hardhat documentation says that "Hardhat supports every currently maintained LTS Node.js version, up to two months after its end-of-life." and "We recommend running Hardhat using the current LTS Node.js version" , so official site of nodejs says that TLS version is 16th version(^16.0.0)

Comment: Official information about versions: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: You seem to have node 17.7.2 installed in a different path that perhaps npx is using while writing `node` in your terminal resolves to some other version. Sounds as if you have node installed from multiple sources in different directories.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found answer, it is really stupid from my side. I working in the directory  ~/SolidityProjects/testProject. But in ~/ I have directory node_modules which I created(I don't know when, I think I made it at random). So this directory somehow covered node_modules from ~/SolidityProjects/testProject. So I deleted it from ~/ and it start working.

Comment: Had the same issue recently on MacOS. I kept getting an error about it using the wrong version of node. I used brew to remove node, using nvm to install and change the version of node - but the error persisted. 

Then I saw that I had a node_modules directory in my root directory and after deleting that - everything started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue here. I was running 17.9 but just downgraded by running `nvm install 16.0.0` and this seems to have worked

Comment: I installed 16.0.0 using `nvm install 16.0.0`. Does not help. Does you somehow specify version in hardhat or you just install new version and create new project with hardhat and error is disappear?

Answer (score 0):

use following commands:

```
nvm install 16.0.0
nvm use v16
node --version
```

node --version to ensure you are using expected nodejs